# How do I extract the schema of entities in Dynamics 365 dynamically using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamics-365

I am trying to build a pipeline that loops over a list of entities from Dynamics 365 and export the data to a parquet file for each entity so I don't have to build a pipeline for each entity.

I am able to parametrize the entity and input it into the source of the pipeline:
[image]

But I am not able to import the schema in the mapping tab.

Is there a way to dynamically import the schema? Or maybe to create another pipeline to extract the schema then import it?

Comment: your aim is to dynamic mapping column in copy activity?

Comment: Yes but I don't need any transformation. I just need the columns to be the same name and format as in Dynamics 365.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Azure Synapse Link for Dataverse (as at today) can export data to the Delta Lake format.  It's just an option via the GUI.  Select the 'Use Spark pool for Delta Lake data conversion job' option when creating a new link:

[image: Synapse Link Delta mode]

More details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-delta-lake

There is a cost for using the Spark pools so consider lowing the frequency, eg hourly, twice-daily, daily etc